# Enable Client Validation dosen't work

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, validation

this is my Script part in Master page :

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.ui.core.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../../Scripts/Validation/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/Validation/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And this is what my Form look like :

```
    <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
                <% using (Html.BeginForm("Inscription", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "search_form", enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
       { %>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
            <div class="editor-label">
           <p>
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mailag) %>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
        <p>
            <%: Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mailag, new { @class = "text longfield" })%>
            <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mailag) %>
            </p>
// the reste of code is similaire to the first editor label :
        </div>
    <% } %>
```

I have folowed the same instruction in the blog to activate the client side but unfortunately it hasn't worked for me :( i think i missed something here ?
The Server validation work so fine.

Comment: Do you have the following key in the web.config - <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" /> ?

Comment: yes it's all ready exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed all `Microsoft*.js` and replaced them with this :

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

All works so fine :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try the following things to verify why the code might not be working for you.

1) Please go to your **browser** and see the `source of the HTML` and ensure that the script files you are trying to include are present there.

2) Also, you can **inspect** the code with `firebug` if you are testing on Mozilla which can be installed as an extension to see whats going wrong.

Hope it helps

Comment: My file are included succufly, and how to inspect code with firebug?

Comment: First you need to add it as an extension in firebug. Go to link http://getfirebug.com/downloads and follow instructions.

Comment: I have install it and all is loaded succfilly

Answer (score 0):

I cant see too much wrong with your code, however it looks like you are missing a reference to 
**MicrosoftAjax.js**. Try including it:

Also, what does your controller look like? Are you checking if the **modelState** is valid?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Course course)
{
  try
  {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      _courses.Add(course);
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View();
  }
  catch
  {
    return View();
  }
}
```

If you dont check for that, the View wont know that the validation failed. And thirdly, have you decorated your class with the correct attributes? For example:

```
public class Course
{
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Course title is required")]
  public string Title { get; set; }

  [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Course can have up to 5 days")]
  public string Days { get; set; }    

}
```

Comment: Yes i'm cheking if my ModelStatIsvalid, server validayion work so fine.